# How to set max height

Tags: android

(android:layout_height="791dp") I used like this to fill the whole screen.

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="791dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomnavigationview"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomnavigationview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/ColorBottomNavi"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/ColorBottomNavi"
        android:background="@color/backgroup"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnavigationview"/>
```

Comment: Can someone help me? thank you !

Comment: did you try 0dp? or match_parent?

Comment: 0dp ? Can you detail ? thanks !

Comment: android:layout_height="0dp" try this

Comment: Use android:layout_heigth="match_parent" for full screen view. 0dp will not work with FrameLayout, will work with constraint layout.

Answer (score 0):

use *match_parent* or *fill_parent*

android:layout_height="match_parent"

android:layout_height="fill_parent"

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/framelayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomnavigationview"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-1dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
     <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomnavigationview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/ColorBottomNavi"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/ColorBottomNavi"
        android:background="@color/backgroup"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomnavigationview"/>
```